# About authentication with tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have installed & configured svn server as well as Tortoise svn on windows. Users creation is also done. Now am trying to open repository with repo browser command of Toroise Svn, then it is asking for the credentials. Though the username & password are valid, it is shwoing the login prompt for 3 times. If i enter the details properly for 3 times, then only it is allowing me to view the contents of the repository. please help me in this regard..

Answer (score 2):

Do you allow Tortoise to save the password? If I remember correctly it will ask you basically on every operation for the password if you do not save the credentials. It might even ask you several times for what you conceive as a single operation...

Answer (score 1):

I think Tortoise SVN asks for login details on every connection.
If you use a single user on all connections you can set up TortoiseSVN to enter them for you by configuring TortoisePLink with additional arguments.

This will allow you to sync and commit without entering your login/password every time.

From [here](http://www.kumarchetan.com/blog/2010/03/22/how-to-save-passwords-in-tortoisesvn/):

> a) Right click on local code repository.
>
> b) Go to TortoiseSVN > Settings
>
> c) Go to “Network”
>
> d) Browse for SSH Client and use following “C:\Program
>      Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoisePlink.exe” – Can be found in TortoiseSVN
>      installation folder in c:\Prgram Files
>
> e) Append following replacing
>      username and password with your user name and password “-l username
>      -pw password”
>
> f) Click OK/Apply

Comment: Nice, although note that your password is then "bare" and visible to anyone who opens your TortoiseSVN settings...